# Accessing ALL SUBSCRIBERS in a Parent BU from a Child BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, database, parent

I have two child BUs and as people are deployed they are added to the ALL SUBSCRIBERS list.  Their STATUS is limited to the Child BU, so an unsubscribe occurs only at the child BU.

Question:  If a user only has access to a single child BU, will they be able to see subscribers from the other BU in ALL SUBSCRIBERS or do they only see subscribers that are in their own BU?

I can't use Publication Lists because there are so many new lists created, and an unsub from one should unsubscribe you from all email in that Child BU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have Business Unit Filters enabled in your account (largely a deprecated feature), you will see subscribers from all business units in All Subscribers. You might want to revoke permissions on All Subscribers from users, if this is an issue.

If you are using standard unsubscribe functionality, the subscriber would be unsubscribed just from the list sent to. The consumer is offered the opportunity to unsubscribe from all on one-click unsubscribe page.

You may want to consider creating a custom landing page for the purpose that unsubscribes the user from the Business Unit's All Subscribers list using. Here is [an example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94731/how-can-i-create-an-unsubevent-using-ampscript-in-a-landing-page) showing how to do this. You would need to modify this code to hard-wire the listid of All Subscribers in the LogUnsubEvent code.

Comment: Thank you.  I think the right approach is to remove access to All Subscribers to the Marketing users.

Comment: @GeorgeRosedale If you have one of the newer additions of SFMC, you may find the roles and permissions have been deliberately broken to encourage "differentiation" between the editions. If you find that going around all your users to remove the permission to view All Subscribers is a bit of a bore, shoot Support a new case to do this by "Business Rule" and get them to do the work it use to take seconds to do.

Comment: Alas, I completed the task just now.  There are about a dozen users with identical access so it wasn't so laborious.  I appreciate the tip!